# Help with Nexus 7

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I want install ubuntu touch in a tablet Nexus 7 2012. I know it is deprecated, but I know it is yet possible although I did not understand the complete steps for do it. Someone can help please?

Comment: There are no builds for the 2012 N7 any longer. It's deprecated, but is no longer supported at all. The images no longer exist on the server. The hardware does not have drivers available for AOSP which would make the system usable on the device, so it is no longer supported.

Comment: You can install Ubuntu Touch preview see my question here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/637136/ubuntu-build-for-the-nexus-7-2012

Answer (score 0):

There have been no builds for the Nexus 7 2012 for well over a year and the system images will soon be deleted if they have not already been.  Plus, the old images are outdated and were not extensively tested.

Unfortunately, due to the lack of binary drivers, it is not possible to install Ubuntu on the Nexus 7 2012 any longer.