# Ubuntu build for the Nexus 7 2012

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Is there a Linux or Ubuntu build for the Nexus 7 2012 which supports touch?

Comment: It is not maintained but try this: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Nexus7/Installation

Answer (score 0):

I installed Ubuntu Touch on a Nexus 7 2012 as a boot option from MultiROM manager using the instructions on Ubuntu Touch preview here:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2093797&page=11
It installs an old preview based on Ubuntu 13.04 and is no longer supported. If anyone sees a newer version of Ubuntu Touch which will run on the Nexus 7 2012, please let me know.